# Linear Algebra: row reducing in order to find the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

When looking for the determinant of some square matrix, one can row reduce until the matrix is in upper triangular form.

My question is: we are allowed to add or subtract multiples of one row to another row, but when we want to multiply/divide a singular row by a constant, we need to multiply the entire determinant by this constant. Why is this?

Thanks!

Comment: This goes back to the definition of the determinant and its basic properties; I'm sure it must be written in your textbook, whatever book on linear algebra it is..

Comment: I don't have one, actually! I just remembered this property while tutoring somebody and forgot the *why* it works. Do you know?

Comment: The formula that expresses the determinant of a matrix in terms of its minors might be helpful to "easily" justify this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace.27s_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The determinant is linear in each of its $n$ arguments, e.g.:
$$
\mbox{det} (c a_1, \ldots, a_n) = c \,\mbox{det} (a_1, \ldots, a_n)
$$
This is called multilinear.
It is a form, because it is a map fron $V^n$ to its field $K$.
Then it switches sign, if you switch two arguments, this is a consequence of it being alternating, i.e. vanishing if two arguments are the same.

This gives: alternating multilinear form

This can be verified with its definition:
$$
\mbox{det} A =
\sum_{\pi\in S_n} \mbox{sgn}(\pi) \,a_{1\,\pi(1)}\cdots a_{n\,\pi(n)}
$$
where $S_n$ is the symmetric group consisting of the permutations of the set 
$\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Or you think of the determinant as signed volume of the paralel epiped spawned by the argument vectors. Scaling a single vector will scale the volume.

And 
$$
\mbox{det}(a_1 + c a_j, \cdots, a_n) =
\mbox{det}(a_1, \cdots, a_n) + c \, \mbox{det}(a_j, \cdots, a_n)
$$
where the second term vanishes because $a_j$ shows up twice, which is the alternating property. This cancels the multiplier $c$.

In the volume picture this would result in a deformation which is not volume changing, which is less obvious for higher dimensions to me.