# When is the proper time to use row operation to find the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

When trying to find the determinant for a square matrix of a normal linear map such as $T: V\rightarrow W$, it's possible to just use elementary row operation to make the square matrix become an upper triangular form and time all the values on the diagonal together.

However, when the $T$ is an operator, $T: V \rightarrow V$, finding the determinant of this matrix for the operator by putting the matrix to an upper triangular form is also an idea, but just using row operation won't give a correct determinant value. Since once the basis of the codomain changes, the basis for the domain will also change. Even though I know we can also find the determinant by just using elementary row operation. The rules are if two rows are switched, then we need to time -1 to the determinant;... However, this is not the way I want to use.

The way I want to use to calculate the determinant of the operator matrix is to find the characteristic polynomial of it.

For example, the matrix is

A=$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 6 & -15\\
1 & 1 & -5\\
1 & 2 & -6\\
\end{pmatrix}$

and in order to find the $P^A_{char}$:

A-$\lambda$=
$\begin{pmatrix}
2-\lambda & 6 & -15\\
1 & 1-\lambda & -5\\
1 & 2 & -6-\lambda\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Then, at this time, can I use row operation to put this $\lambda$ matrix to become an upper triangular matrix to find the characteristic polynomial？ Since A-$\lambda$ is also an operator, I think just using row operation won't be correct, but after some trials (if there are no calculation mistakes) the row operation indeed works. Thus, I think I must misunderstand something. Any helps? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this helpful? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168357/linear-algebra-row-reducing-in-order-to-find-the-determinant?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but the fact is that this is not entirely helpful to me. Since I'm curious about the reason that I don't need to time -1 when switching the row of the $\lambda$ matrix. However, the $\lambda$ matrix and A matrix are both matrices of operators. The former one doesn't need to time -1 when changing two rows, but the latter one needs to time -1 when changing two rows. This means that I can just treat the $\lambda$ matrix as a normal matrix and do row operation, but I can't do this to matrix A, even though both of them are matrices for operators

Comment: If you are finding $\lambda$ by putting the determinant = 0, you can swap rows because 0 = -0.

Comment: So since the $\lambda$ matrix is the operator $T-\lambda$, and in order to compute the characteristic polynomial, the operator $T-\lambda$ should be noninvertible and this means the determinant of the $\lambda$ matrix should be zero, we default the determinant of the $\lambda$ matrix is already zero and then do row operation to the matrix. It seems that before any operations, we already know the determinant is zero, and all we need to do is to find a $\lambda$-relavent formula and let it equal zero. Is this right?

Comment: A linear map $T : V \to W$ between two different vector spaces does not have a determinant. There is no way to define what determinant should be when $V \ne W$. *Determinants are only defined for linear maps from a vector space to itself*, which seems to be what you mean by "operator" here. So every time you have ever found a determinant by using row operations, you have done so on an operator.